# How do i stop drag select on wpf data grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, drag

Hi all this might sound trivial but I want to stop drag select on `WPF` `DataGrid`

I have a simple grid like

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionMode="Extended">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding .}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

how can I stop multiple selection on click drag but and have multiple selection by Shift and Ctrl.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

[Mikolaytis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38206511/1792830) is incomplete.  With that solution, clicking an unselected row selects all rows between it and the first selected row above it, for as long as the mouse button is down.  This is a side effect of DataGrid._isDraggingSelection still being true, which is evaluated in other mouse-event-driven operations.

[Il Vic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38208046/1792830), while I did not try it, is far more complex than necessary.

Instead, in the override for DataGrid.OnMouseMove() (as was done in Mikolaytis's answer), call private method DataGrid.EndDragging(), via reflection:

```
public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    private static readonly FieldInfo s_isDraggingSelectionField = 
        typeof(DataGrid).GetField("_isDraggingSelection", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    private static readonly MethodInfo s_endDraggingMethod =
        typeof(DataGrid).GetMethod("EndDragging", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    // DataGrid.OnMouseMove() serves no other purpose than to execute click-drag-selection.
    // Bypass that, and stop 'is dragging selection' mode for DataGrid
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)(s_isDraggingSelectionField?.GetValue(this) ?? false))
            s_endDraggingMethod.Invoke(this, new object[0]);
    }
}
```

Put simply, after drag-selection is started, the next mouse move event ends it.

Answer (score 1):

Try that hack: create a class that inherits [`DataGrid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) and override [`OnMouseMove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.onmousemove(v=vs.110).aspx) without calling `base.OnMouseMove`

Comment: it kills drag drop behavior then

Comment: so add if and check if it's a drag drop

Comment: sorry, that's the only easy way i see in this situation.

Comment: yea that's what I feel for last 2 days, MS MS !

Comment: In WPF actually lots of cases like that. You need to do a basic thing but you need to step through lots of hacks or forget about that feature.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataGrid` control is not designed for customizing the selection gestures, anyway some hacks can be performed to reach your target.
First of all we need an helper class:

```
public static class ReflectionHelper
{
    public static T GetPropertyValue<T>(object owner, string propertyName) where T : class
    {
        Type ownerType = owner.GetType();
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = ownerType.GetProperty(propertyName,
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        while (propertyInfo == null)
        {
            ownerType = ownerType.BaseType;
            propertyInfo = ownerType.GetProperty(propertyName,
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        }

        return propertyInfo.GetValue(owner, null) as T;
    }

    public static void Execute(object owner, string methodName, params object[] parameters)
    {
        Type ownerType = owner.GetType();
        MethodInfo methodInfo = ownerType.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        while (methodInfo == null)
        {
            ownerType = ownerType.BaseType;
            methodInfo = ownerType.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        }
        methodInfo.Invoke(owner, parameters);
    }
}
```

I do not like it, but reflection is needed. First of all we need to create our own `DataGridRowHeader` in order to change its `OnClick` code:

```
public class DataGridRowHeader : System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridRowHeader
{
    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        if (Mouse.Captured == this)
        {
            base.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }
        DataGrid dataGridOwner = ReflectionHelper.GetPropertyValue<DataGrid>(this, "DataGridOwner");
        DataGridRow parentRow = ReflectionHelper.GetPropertyValue<DataGridRow>(this, "ParentRow");

        if (dataGridOwner != null && parentRow != null)
        {
            ReflectionHelper.Execute(dataGridOwner, "HandleSelectionForRowHeaderAndDetailsInput", parentRow, false);
        }
    }        
}
```

All we want to do is to pass false (instead of true) as the second parameter of the method `HandleSelectionForRowHeaderAndDetailsInput`.

We need to handle the DataGrid's cells by creating our own DataGridCell:

```
public class DataGridCell : System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell
{
    static DataGridCell()
    {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(DataGridCell), 
            UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, 
            new MouseButtonEventHandler(DataGridCell.OnAnyMouseLeftButtonDownThunk), true);
    }

    private static void OnAnyMouseLeftButtonDownThunk(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ((DataGridCell)sender).OnAnyMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    }

    private void OnAnyMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        bool isKeyboardFocusWithin = base.IsKeyboardFocusWithin;
        bool flag = (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control;
        DataGrid dataGridOwner = ReflectionHelper.GetPropertyValue<DataGrid>(this, "DataGridOwner");
        if (isKeyboardFocusWithin && !flag && !e.Handled && this.IsSelected)
        {
            if (dataGridOwner != null)
            {
                ReflectionHelper.Execute(dataGridOwner, "HandleSelectionForCellInput",
                    this, false, true, false);

                if (!this.IsEditing && !this.IsReadOnly)
                {
                    dataGridOwner.BeginEdit(e);
                    e.Handled = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (!isKeyboardFocusWithin || !this.IsSelected || flag)
        {
            if (!isKeyboardFocusWithin)
            {
                base.Focus();
            }
            if (dataGridOwner != null)
            {
                ReflectionHelper.Execute(dataGridOwner, "HandleSelectionForCellInput",
                    this, Mouse.Captured == null && flag, true, false);
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

A simple `DataGridCellsPresenter` is also needed:

```
public class DataGridCellsPresenter : System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridCellsPresenter
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new DataGridCell(); /* the one in our namespace */
    }
}
```

It will say to the `DataGrid` to use our `DataGridCell`.
Now, of course, we have to create a default style (it should be placed in the `Window` resources) for forcing the `DataGrid` to use our stuff:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGridRow}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Border Name="DGR_Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Control.BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                        <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding DataGridRow.ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        <local:DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DataGridRow.DetailsVisibility}" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=AreRowDetailsFrozen, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}}" />
                        <local:DataGridRowHeader SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}}" />
                    </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I hope it can help.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but somehow it has no effect, I need to look into the solution what isn't right will reply back thanks again.

Comment: OnClick is never hit :-s

Comment: It is strange: I tested my solution with VS2010 (.NET 4.0) and it works. Did you put the style in your window's resources?

Comment: have it in local control resource, it is being applied as if I put a background color to border that color is applied, but I am not sure if this header is applied

Comment: ah, it seems to work only on row header and they were hidden, can I extend this to entire row somehow ?

Comment: Sure @Muds, it is possible. Please, take a look to my edit

Answer (score 0):

That works for me:

```
public partial class DataGridView : DataGrid
{
    // ...
    
    protected override void OnPreviewMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && SelectionMode == DataGridSelectionMode.Extended)
        {
            // Do some stuff which you need for dragging
        }

        base.OnPreviewMouseMove(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnMouseMove(e);
    }
    
    // ...
}
```